# Upgrade process for Intel CPUs

Tags: cpu, motherboard, computer-building

Sorry for the basic question, this is my first build.

I currently have an Intel 5820 CPU in a Sabretooth X99 mobo with a Noctua cooler. I use my desktop for very demanding machine learning applications, so I like the idea of having more cores/threads.

If I purchase something like a Xeon E5-2650, which I believe is [compatible](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_X99/HelpDesk_CPU/) with my mobo, what is the installation process? Is it simply a case of physically swapping over the CPUs? Thanks!

---

If anyone has experience of this combo, I would be very grateful to hear it. According to the Asus site: "Intel Xeon Processor Family is designed for servers. Some features may not support when installed on X99 series chipsets. For more details, refer to ASUS support site at http://support.asus.com."

Comment: You think it's compatible, might want to be 100%, if it's the same socket yes it's that's simple

Comment: Use ASUS specifications instead of third-party website.  Be sure your bios matches the required bios version but that's obvious

Comment: When asus says that "some features may not support" they might be referring to CPU features like turbo boost, hyperthreading, vPRO etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [i7 5820](http://ark.intel.com/products/82932/Intel-Core-i7-5820K-Processor-15M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz?q=5820) is a socket 2011 chip. Most of the time you can swap this for another socket 2011 chip.

Things you want to check are:

1. Can the motherboard supply enough power (not all do support very power hungry CPU's, but the one you have atm already has a 140W TPD, so this should not be a problem).
2. Does the motherboard firmware (e.g. UEFI or BIOS) support the CPU. If it does not then it might not enable some features (like 2nd level cache) or it might not boot at all. Most of the time this means checking the firmware notes vs supported CPU's.

Other then that, I am reasonably sure that it *will simply work*. But to be 100% sure do contact Asus. Only they can guarantee it.